# Returning fields from multiple entities from ASP.NET Web API v2

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-entities, anonymous-types

I am building an ASP.NET Web API v2 project where I am using Entity Framework v6 to model the database. So far I have been able to return a collection of objects only when the collection is of one object type. i.e. `<Customer>` or `<Order>`.

I would like to return a collection of objects but include a field (or property) from a related entity (an association is present). I think I have the LINQ to Entity query setup properly but I am not sure how to return the resultant anonymous type to the jQuery method that calls the API.

```
[Route("api/clients/GetAllClientsWithPaymentMethod")]
[HttpGet]
public NOT-SURE-WHAT-RETURN-TYPE-SHOULD-BE GetAllClientsWithPaymentMethod()
{
  using (var context = new MyEntities())
  {
    context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var query = from client in context.Clients
                select new
                {
                  ClientID = client.ID,
                  CompanyName = client.CompanyName,
                  Phone = client.Phone,
                  Email = client.email
                  PaymentMethod = client.payments.PaymentMethod
                };
    return query.ToList();
  }
}
```

Is an anonymous type the proper way to return this information? If so, what should the return type be? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a class called Client that has all the fields you would like to return.

e.g.

```
public class Client
{
    private int ID;
    private string companyName;
    private string phoneNumber;
    private string email;
    private string payMethod;


    public Client()
    {
    }

    //...etc
```

}

In the controller I would create a group of client objects from the results of the database query and then I would just return an IEnumerable of clients e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<Client> GetAllClientsWithPaymentMethod()
```

On the client side you can read the content of the message with the serializer that you are using.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/clients/GetAllClientsWithPaymentMethod");

IEnumerable<Client> returnedClients = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Client>(new[] { JsonFormatter() }).Result;
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to creating the class vs just returning a collection of objects using `IEnumerable<Object> GetAllClientsWithPaymentMethod()`

Comment: Yes, you can do a lot with a [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx).  In this case, it seems like your trying to pass information from the DB to front end using jQuery to make the rest call which doesn't know about the "Client" class. I would maybe use [this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and return the class object as described and setup your webapi server to use json serialization.

Comment: Like this:  `HttpSelfHostConfiguration config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("127.0.0.1");JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
            {
                PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All,
                TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.All
            };
            config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter() { SerializerSettings = settings });            var host = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
            host.OpenAsync().Wait();`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. You are correct that my end goal is to bring back the results as a JSON collection via jQuery. I remain confused why it is better to setup a new class to hold the results of the query as opposed to returning a collection of `Object`. Please don't take my reply as being "snarky" or "antagonistic", rather I remain confused because it seems to me the point of using an anonymous class would be defeated by creating a new class just to hold the results that will be serialized to a JSON collection.

Comment: Your welcome for the help! Didn't receive any snark over here. The class would make it easier to organize the fields within your object. Also it will allow the webAPI framework to correctly serialize the object when it returns it. If the server is setup to use the JSON serializer when you return `IEnumberable<Client>` it will use the correct serializer to serialize the object into the content of the response.